# HandleMouseMove fired from mousemove event listener in React Js does not use updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, mouseevent

**What works:**
My state variable "dragging" is set to true when the react onMouseDown event fires on the trigger.
Also, "dragging" is set to false when mouseUp fires anywhere on the screen from a classic event listener.
My mousemove listener fires the handleMouseMove function.

**What does not work:**
handleMouseMove checks if dragging is true, if it is true, it should print "I'm Dragging" but it looks like it never becomes true for handleMouseMove. ????

How can I get it to work and print "I'm Dragging" if dragging is true?

**Note:**
Debugging with a useEffect that fires every time dragging changes, confirms that in fact, it changes from true to false correctly whenever react onMouseDown and classic mouseup events fire.

```
export const useDrag = () => {

const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove );
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp );
    
  return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove );
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, []);

function handleMouseDown (e)  {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    setDragging(true);
  };

function handleMouseUp(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    setDragging(false);
  }

function handleMouseMove(e){
    if(dragging) console.log("I'm Dragging");
  }

const bindTrigger = {
    onMouseDown: handleMouseDown,
}

return [ bindTrigger ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bind the handlers on mount in the `useEffect`, but since the `useEffect` doesn't have any dependencies, it doesn't update the bound functions when they are re-created (which happens on each render). So for the handlers, `dragging` is always `false`.

You should only bind the handlers to the `window` when `dragging` is `true`. Move the `move` and `up` handlers into the `useEffect()`, and make it dependent on `dragging`. If `dragging` is `false` it would only call the cleanup function to remove the handlers from `window`.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const useDrag = () => {
  const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!dragging) return;

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
      if (dragging) console.log("I'm Dragging");
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      setDragging(false);
    }

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, [dragging]);
  
  function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    setDragging(true);
  };

  const bindTrigger = {
    onMouseDown: handleMouseDown,
  }

  return [bindTrigger];
}

const Demo = () => {
  const [bindTrigger] = useDrag();

  return (
    <div {...bindTrigger}>Drag me</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```